# With Kotlin write to SD-card on Android

Tags: kotlin, android-sdcard

I have read a lot of questions and answers, but are not really satisfied and successful
My Problem: write with Kotlin to a sdcard to a specific directory

Working is

```
        var filenamex = "export.csv"
        var patt = getExternalFilesDirs(null)
        var path = patt[1]
//create fileOut object
        var fileOut = File(path, filenamex)
//create a new file
        fileOut.createNewFile()
```

with getExternalFIlesDirs() I get the external storage and the sdcard. With path = patt[1] i get the adress of my sd-card.

this is

```
"/storage/105E-XXXX/Android/data/com.example.myApp/files"
```

This works to write data in this directory.
But I would like to write into an other directory, for example

```
"/sdcard/myApp"
```

A lot of examples  say, this should work, bit it does not.
So I tried to take

```
"/storage/105E-XXXX/myApp"
```

Why doesn't it work? Ist the same beginning of storage /storage/105E-XXXX/, so it is MY sd-card.?
As I mentioned, it works on the sd-card, so it is not a problem of write-permission to the sdcard?

Any idea?
(I also failed with FileOutputStream and other things)

Comment: You're not granted universal access to entire SD card, you can only write to your apps specific directories while others remain inaccessible or read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Try Out this..

```
    var filenamex = "export.csv"

    var path = getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//your desired folder"

    var fileOut = File(path, filenamex)

    fileOut.createNewFile()
```

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() returns "/storage/emulated/0", which is the internal storage of the smartphone, but not the sdcard

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
private fun getExternalSdCardPath(): String? {
    val storageManager = getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager

    val storageVolumes: List<StorageVolume> =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            storageManager.storageVolumes
        } else {
            try {
                val getVolumeListMethod =
                    StorageManager::class.java.getMethod("getVolumeList")
                getVolumeListMethod.invoke(storageManager) as Array<Any>
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emptyArray<Any>()
            }.toList() as List<StorageVolume>
        }

    for (storageVolume in storageVolumes) {
        if (storageVolume.isRemovable) {
            return storageVolume.directory?.absolutePath
        }
    }

    return null
}
 val externalSdCardPath = getExternalSdCardPath()
    if (externalSdCardPath != null) {
        val filePath = externalSdCardPath + "your desired directory"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).